# Crash when waking up on Sierra 10.12.1 (16B2555)

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake, crash

I believe these crashes started after the recent upgrade to Sierra.

Full computer specs:
MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014),
2,2 GHz Intel Core i7,
16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3,
Intel Iris Pro 1536 MB.

It now happens once a day when waking up from slumber, the poor guy pops out that Black Screen of Death ("Your computer restarted because of a problem. Press a key or wait a few seconds to continue starting up.")

This is the crash report for today:

```
Anonymous UUID:       E374B9D8-ABD4-56BF-037B-75B000F7D4A2

Mon Dec 12 15:21:41 2016

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 4 caller 0xffffff800d2065ea): Kernel trap at 0xffffff7f8f8f3ffc, type 13=general protection, registers:
CR0: 0x0000000080010033, CR2: 0x00007ff5f082b000, CR3: 0x000000000eb9f02b, CR4: 0x00000000001627e0
RAX: 0xc0d140a9c0a98081, RBX: 0xffffff8040c5ccd0, RCX: 0x000000000000000a, RDX: 0x00000000000003fe
RSP: 0xffffff92240bb680, RBP: 0xffffff92240bb6c0, RSI: 0x0000000000000001, RDI: 0xffffff802ebb8000
R8:  0xffffff80371d4608, R9:  0xffffff92240bb8e0, R10: 0xffffff800d6bc850, R11: 0xffffff92240bbb18
R12: 0xffffff92240bb8e0, R13: 0xffffff802ebb8000, R14: 0xffffff81aa2f1000, R15: 0xffffff80371d4608
RFL: 0x0000000000010202, RIP: 0xffffff7f8f8f3ffc, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0x00007ff5f082b000, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x4, PL: 0

Backtrace (CPU 4), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff81eac55df0 : 0xffffff800d0f368c 
0xffffff81eac55e70 : 0xffffff800d2065ea 
0xffffff81eac56050 : 0xffffff800d0a5743 
0xffffff81eac56070 : 0xffffff7f8f8f3ffc 
0xffffff92240bb6c0 : 0xffffff7f8f90c235 
0xffffff92240bb750 : 0xffffff7f8f90ca16 
0xffffff92240bb770 : 0xffffff800d6bc88e 
0xffffff92240bb7b0 : 0xffffff7f8f90ca9d 
0xffffff92240bb800 : 0xffffff7f8f8b0888 
0xffffff92240bb820 : 0xffffff7f8f8b065e 
0xffffff92240bb890 : 0xffffff7f8f8b0a17 
0xffffff92240bb910 : 0xffffff7f8fda61fc 
0xffffff92240bb980 : 0xffffff800d6bc88e 
0xffffff92240bb9c0 : 0xffffff7f8fda67e8 
0xffffff92240bba10 : 0xffffff7f8f8b065e 
0xffffff92240bba80 : 0xffffff7f8f8b0a17 
0xffffff92240bbb00 : 0xffffff7f8f8aefdc 
0xffffff92240bbb80 : 0xffffff800d6ee181 
0xffffff92240bbcc0 : 0xffffff800d1c5f28 
0xffffff92240bbdd0 : 0xffffff800d0f843c 
0xffffff92240bbe30 : 0xffffff800d0d5f61 
0xffffff92240bbe80 : 0xffffff800d0e9957 
0xffffff92240bbf10 : 0xffffff800d1f26ae 
0xffffff92240bbfb0 : 0xffffff800d0a5f66 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl(3.13.74)[BC16864D-447E-3F3C-BA1A-280868E043BB]@0xffffff7f8f8ae000->0xffffff7f8f8b7fff
         com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferAzul(10.2)[46436999-2331-3783-B1CE-C5EC456E1DC3]@0xffffff7f8f8ba000->0xffffff7f8fa09fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[C29002A1-DF76-3A8E-8D67-D70922DF86AE]@0xffffff7f8da21000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[4F7FB6AD-2498-3F71-827C-ED7AA4BF2511]@0xffffff7f8df57000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(288.15)[51C08EBC-F91D-34E3-90CC-8F3D3011F8B2]@0xffffff7f8f76d000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily(31)[B14DC3D3-7250-3DA3-BF50-C666EBEDAF4C]@0xffffff7f8e4c4000
            dependency: com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl(3.13.74)[BC16864D-447E-3F3C-BA1A-280868E043BB]@0xffffff7f8f8ae000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[D01B501C-E5B8-36AC-930C-978C205EFEFF]@0xffffff7f8e584000
         com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsDevicePolicy(3.13.74)[D25D47B3-EB1B-3EC4-B775-A2D5154FC02B]@0xffffff7f8fda0000->0xffffff7f8fdaafff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl(3.13.74)[19D93391-DAD9-3A7B-BB38-B3673AC90588]@0xffffff7f8fd7c000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[4F7FB6AD-2498-3F71-827C-ED7AA4BF2511]@0xffffff7f8df57000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[C29002A1-DF76-3A8E-8D67-D70922DF86AE]@0xffffff7f8da21000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[D01B501C-E5B8-36AC-930C-978C205EFEFF]@0xffffff7f8e584000
            dependency: com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl(3.13.74)[BC16864D-447E-3F3C-BA1A-280868E043BB]@0xffffff7f8f8ae000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: displaypolicyd

Mac OS version:
16B2555

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 16.1.0: Thu Oct 13 21:26:57 PDT 2016; root:xnu-3789.21.3~60/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 8941AC1C-B084-37DE-8A34-4CE638C5CFC9
Kernel slide:     0x000000000ce00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff800d000000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff800cf00000
System model name: MacBookPro11,2 (Mac-3CBD00234E554E41)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 83032577784129
last loaded kext at 83015138752882: com.apple.driver.usb.cdc    5.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7f9001f000, size 28672)
last unloaded kext at 81472398280525: com.apple.driver.usb.cdc  5.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7f9001f000, size 28672)
loaded kexts:
com.techsmith.TACC  1.0.3
com.Cycling74.driver.Soundflower    2
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 3.1
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.7.0d0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.23.11
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsDevicePolicy  3.13.74
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.4
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   278.23
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD5000Graphics   10.2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    5.0.1f7
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 5.0.1f7
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    208
com.apple.driver.AppleCameraInterface   5.57.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferAzul  10.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.0.8
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.9.10
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.13
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 404.20.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 251
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  251
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.BootCache 40
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext  366.1.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  295.20.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  326
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   1110.4.1a8
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   172
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   197
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 278.23
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    525
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   153.1
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   5.0.1f7
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerTransport  5.0.1f7
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   5.0.1f7
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 278.23
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 278.23
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   205.11
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.13.74
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d8
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.13.74
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    288.15
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.14d1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   394
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  131.1.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   394
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 258
com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.1
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.1
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    540
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext    1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    288
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    4.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    4.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    4.1.6
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 6.2.3
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1200.12.2
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleBusPowerController    1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 444.20.3
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  5.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
Model: MacBookPro11,2, BootROM MBP112.0138.B17, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2,2 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.18f15
Graphics: Intel Iris Pro, Intel Iris Pro, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54343147533641465238412D50422020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54343147533641465238412D50422020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x134), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.21.171.47.1a8)
Bluetooth: Version 5.0.1f7, 3 services, 17 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM0256F, 251 GB
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: USB3.0 Hub
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: USB2.0 Hub
USB Device: Keyboard Hub
USB Device: Apple Keyboard
USB Device: 2.4G Keyboard Mouse
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 17.1
```

If there's any other info I can add to shed some light on the matter, I'd be happy to provide it.

Comment: First suspects are always non-Apple kexts. Idk what com.techsmith.TACC is, but Soundflower would always be a prime suspect since about Mavericks.

Comment: Appreciate the input. I'll try removing Soundflower and update soon. FYI com.techsmith is for Camtasia, the screen recorder.

Comment: Ahhh... then that would definitely promote it to prime candidate, as the crash was in displaypolicyd.

Comment: Was your computer plugged into a monitor? This happens to me when I unplug my MBP from my monitor sometimes.

Comment: @owlswipe Yes! It's nearly always plugged into a monitor, but it always happens while plugged and waking up, not while disconnecting it. Do you have Camtasia installed as well? Did you find any solution? I'll follow Tetsujin's recommendation and uninstall it.

Comment: @JohnnyKutnowski I don't have Camtasia; try uninstalling it and report back.